# How to enable the teleportation for genesis hash in the parity-bridges

Tags: parachain, rust, xcm, substrate-parachain-template, parity-bridges-common

How to write the genesis hash in the teleportation to enable the communication of two chains through bridge.By adding the genesis hash it will be easier for the one chain to reach another chain. Otherwise it is giving the error of unreachable

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

I think the `NetworkId` `ByGenesis` should be described as the hash of the genesis block of your chain. It can be queried using the chain::getBlockHash(0) RPC request as depicted below (example uses polkadot).

Once you have the genesis hash you can use [hex_literal](https://docs.rs/hex-literal/latest/hex_literal/) to create the appropriate type.

Hope this helps!

[image]